# Set default values in Select option in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony1

I am using the widget

```
sfWidgetFormChoice(array (
  'choices' => CountryPeer::getAllCountry(),
))
```

and validator as

```
sfValidatorChoice(array (
  'choices' => array_keys(CountryPeer::getAllCountry()),
))
```

I get a select element as

```
<select id="country" name="reg_form[country]">
  <option value="1">India</option>
  <option value="2">Srilanka</option>
</select>
```

I want to add a option `--Select Countries--` as default:

```
<option value="">--Select Countries--</option>
```

so that it should throw an required error, if i am not selecting any country.

Comment: please format code as `code sample`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, add the option to the array of choices, but not into the validator, so it will throw the error:

```
$def_val = array(-1=>"--Select Countries--");

$sel_choices = array_merge($def_val,CountryPeer::getAllCountry());

sfWidgetFormChoice(array (
  'choices' => $sel_choices,
))

sfValidatorChoice(array (
  'choices' => array_keys(CountryPeer::getAllCountry()),
))
```

And then set the "-1" option as the default value:

```
 $your_form->setDefault('country', -1);
```

Should do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can set required option to false

> sfValidatorChoice(array (   'required'
>   => false,   'choices' => array_keys(CountryPeer::getAllCountry()),
>   ))

it should work.

Comment: as this field is required and cannot be null, so has to keep required=true